# Selenium Python 2.7: how to fill in the gaps?

Tags: python, selenium

everyone! I'm new to coding and I'm trying to write a webcrawler using Selenium with Python 2.7. I'm still on an early stage, however I've been having problems filling in the gaps of the website. It's https://comtrade.un.org/data/ from the UN. I've already tried inspecting the webpage elements and using different methods (find_element_by_id, find_element_by_class, find_element_by_name, send_keys, etc.), but none seems to work.

Here's my code thus far:

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

HEADER = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
BASE_URL = 'https://comtrade.un.org/data/'

def initialize_webdriver():
    profile = webdriver.Chrome()
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", HEADER)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(profile)

    # driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.set_window_size(1180, 980)

    return driver 

def main():
    # driver = initialize_webdriver()   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(BASE_URL)


    for period in driver.find_element_by_class('s2id_periods'):
        period.clear()
        period.send_keys('2013')
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `filling in the gaps of the website`? Can you sumup your _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: The website has a couple of gaps that need filling in order to extract data. I need the exports from a specific group of countries (the  55 african ones). The website, nevertheless, doesn't let me download it all, because the file would be too big. Therefore, I have to download the exports from each of the countries one by one. What I'd like to automate is this process. My idea was to create an array with the africa countries and loop it, while extracting the data, compiling and reporting it in a way that suits me.